# Is $PRA$ + $TI({\epsilon_0})$ mutually interpretable with some theory in the language of set theory?

Tags: set-theory, forcing, mathematical-philosophy, peano-arithmetic

As is well known, the following theory is equiconsistent with $PA$:

> $ZFC$ with the axiom of infinity replaced by its negation.

Since this theory is equiconsistent with $PA$, it would seem reasonable to infer (wouldn't it?) that the consistency of '$ZFC$ with the axiom of infinity replaced by its negation' could be provable in "$PRA$ + $TI({\epsilon_0})$.

So what 'theory of sets'(?) is mutually interpretable with "$PRA$ + $TI({\epsilon_0})$? Also, can one define a notion of forcing in the aforementioned theory?

(If this seems too silly a question, please let me know and I will delete....)

Comment: What do the underlines and single quote marks mean?  Or can we delete them?

Comment: @MattF.:  Feel free to edit according to  whatever the standard form for writing $T$ + $Axiom$ is, where $T$ is some formal theory.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: ZFC with the axiom of infinity replaced by its negation is *not* a fragment of ZFC (it is even inconsistent with ZFC). A fragment of ZFC equiconsistent with PA is ZFC with the axiom of infinity *dropped*.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  You are, of course, correct.  Please let me know if the corrections are suitable, and if not, what would be, and I will re-edit.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the consistency of "ZFC with the axiom of infinity replaced by its negation" is provable in "PRA + TI($\epsilon_0$)".  Technically one has to also show that "PRA + TI($\epsilon_0$)" can prove the equiconsistency result (since it already proves the consistency of PA), but these are fairly natural theories so that shouldn't be a problem.

I'm not aware of a natural fragment of ZFC equiconsistent with "PRA + TI($\epsilon_0$)", and can't think of any reason there would be one.  It's sort of remarkable that ZFC has a fragment which matches up perfectly with PA (which is mostly a reflection of how PA is a very natural theory).

Comment: Thanks.  Is it also possible to define notions of forcing in $PRA$ + $TI({\epsilon_0})$ over the ground model "ZFC with the axiom of infinity replaced by its negation"?  Also, since it's possible to interpret $Q$  in terms of sets and $PRA$ is an extension of $Q$, has anyone used the set interpretation of $Q$ to derive a set interpretation of $PRA$ + $TI({\epsilon_0})$?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: It's surely possible to define some kind of notion of forcing in PRA+TI($\epsilon_0$) (or even just PRA), but I'm not aware of any work doing this, nor am I aware of work on set interpretations of TI($\epsilon_0$).